# jQuery Dialog dynamic add buttons

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have the following problem. I'm trying to add dynamic buttons in a modal dialog with iframe.
I have Iframe dialog box with standard buttons (like close, ok..). After new content
is loaded by iframe url scr attribute, i need dynamic add new button, for example "register".
My code:

```
var iDlg= $('<iframe src=price.php?code="'+uCode+'" frameborder="0" />').dialog({
                modal: true,
                dialogClass: 'priceBox',
                title: 'Detail',        
                height: 400,
                width: 500,
                draggable: false,
                resizable: false,
                //show: "fade",
                buttons: {
                "close": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }       
            }).width(480);
```

source of price.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var opt = {
            buttons: {
                'New button...': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        };
        $(iDlg).dialog('option', opt);


    });
    </script>
```

But, this solution doesn't work. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Could be a typo but it says `.iDlg` instead of `iDlg`. Also, is that variable accessible from where you use it?

Comment: Same :( `iDlg` is not defined (error in price.php)

Answer (score 3):

You have to tell it what option you're passing in.  In this case, you are passing values for the "buttons" option:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var btns = {
       'New button...': function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    };
    iDlg.dialog('option', 'buttons', btns);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In price.php, have you tried passing opt to a function in the parent, i.e., `parent.addButton(opt);`

Then in the parent frame you'd have

```
function addButton(opt)
{
    $(iDlg).dialog('option', opt);
}
```

Of course, iDlg needs to have the correct scope (global) in the parent.